# I try to insall gpsd-3.21 for using ubxtool but I have problems

Tags: apt, python, compiling, gcc, make

https://fossies.org/linux/gpsd/build.adoc
There was problem during the installation using this link. After entering scons and scons chek command.

```
    jhkim@***:~/Desktop/gpsd-3.21$ scons udev-install
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons version: 3.0.1
scons is running under Python version: 3.6.9.final.0
gpsd version: 3.21
This system is: linux
Checking whether the C compiler works... (cached) yes
Checking if compiler accepts -pthread... (cached) yes
Checking whether the C++ compiler works... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file curses.h... (cached) yes
Checking pkg-config for ncurses... (cached) no
Checking pkg-config for libusb-1.0... (cached) no
Checking for C library librt... (cached) yes
Checking for C library libnsl... (cached) yes
Checking for C library libsocket... (cached) no
Checking for C library libm... (cached) yes
Checking for C library libthr... (cached) no
Checking pkg-config for dbus-1... (cached) no
Turning off dbus-export support, library not found.
Checking pkg-config for bluez... (cached) no
Turning off Bluetooth support, library not found.
Checking for C type in_port_t... (cached) yes
Checking whether SUN_LEN is declared... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file linux/can.h... (cached) yes
You have kernel CANbus available.
Checking if compiler is C11... (cached) yes
Checking whether __STDC_NO_ATOMICS__ is declared... (cached) no
Checking for C header file stdatomic.h... (cached) yes
Checking whether __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__ is declared... (cached) yes
Checking whether __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__ is declared... (cached) yes
Checking whether __BYTE_ORDER__ is declared... (cached) yes
Your compiler has built-in endianness support.
Checking for C header file arpa/inet.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file netdb.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file netinet/in.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file netinet/ip.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file sys/sysmacros.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file sys/socket.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file sys/un.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file syslog.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file termios.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file winsock2.h... (cached) no
Checking if sizeof(time_t) is 64 bits... (cached) yes
Checking for C function cfmakeraw()... (cached) yes
Checking for C function clock_gettime()... (cached) yes
Checking for C function daemon()... (cached) yes
Checking for C function fcntl()... (cached) yes
Checking for C function fork()... (cached) yes
Checking for C function getopt_long()... (cached) yes
Checking for C function gmtime_r()... (cached) yes
Checking for C function inet_ntop()... (cached) yes
Checking for C function strlcat()... (cached) no
Checking for C function strlcpy()... (cached) no
Checking for C function strptime()... (cached) yes
Checking for C function sincos()... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file sys/timepps.h... (cached) yes
Checking whether TIOCMIWAIT is declared... (cached) yes
Checking that xsltproc can make man pages... (cached) yes
Checking pkg-config for QtNetwork... (cached) no
Turning off Qt support, library not found.
Checking if compiler accepts -Wall... (cached) yes
Checking if compiler accepts -Wcast-align... (cached) yes
Checking if compiler accepts -Wextra... (cached) yes
Checking if compiler accepts -Wimplicit-fallthrough... (cached) yes
Checking if compiler accepts -Wmissing-declarations... (cached) yes
Checking if compiler accepts -Wmissing-prototypes... (cached) yes
Checking if compiler accepts -Wno-missing-field-initializers... (cached) yes
Checking if compiler accepts -Wno-uninitialized... (cached) yes
Checking if compiler accepts -Wpointer-arith... (cached) yes
Checking if compiler accepts -Wreturn-type... (cached) yes
Checking if compiler accepts -Wstrict-prototypes... (cached) yes
Checking if compiler accepts -Wvla... (cached) yes
Checking whether python program exists.../usr/bin/python
Checking Python lib dir... (cached) /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Ensure your PYTHONPATH includes /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/
Checking Python config vars... ok
(cached) Checking Python target version... (cached) 3.6
Checking Python module serial (pyserial)... (cached) 
WARNING: ubxtool and zerk are missing optional runtime module serial
Checking Python module cairo (pycairo)... (cached) found
Checking Python module gi (pygobject)... (cached) found
Checking pkg-config for gtk+-3.0... (cached) no
WARNING: gtk+-3.0 not found.
WARNING: xgps and xgpsspeed are missing runtime dependencies
Altered configuration variables:
dbus_export = False (default True): enable DBUS export support
bluez = False (default True): BlueZ support for Bluetooth devices
qt = False (default True): build Qt bindings
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
Install file: "systemd/gpsdctl@.service" as "/lib/systemd/system/gpsdctl@.service"
scons: *** [/lib/systemd/system/gpsdctl@.service] /lib/systemd/system/gpsdctl@.service: No such file or directory
scons: building terminated because of errors.
WARNING: xgps and xgpsspeed are missing runtime dependencies
WARNING: ubxtool and zerk are missing optional runtime module serial
```

---

What should I do to solve it?

Comment: Why ask here?  You haven't provided any OS/release details.  Also server/desktop is useful, as I note it looking for GTK & Qt toolkits & finding nothing  appropriate..

Answer (score 2):

To complement [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1267820/66509) about using repositories.

I believe, that 3.17 and 3.21 do not have serious differences.

In anyway, you need to get build dependencies and build tools get it compiled:

1. Open Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and enable *Source Code*, confirm package cache reload
2. Open terminal and get all needed build tools and dependencies with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   sudo apt-get build-dep gpsd
   ```
3. Compile the *gpsd-3.21* as you planned to do.

Answer (score 1):

For most purposes installing `gpsd` and `ubxtool` can be done through the APT package manager instead of building from source:

```bsh
$ sudo apt install gpsd gpsd-clients
```

Comment: Thank you ... but I want to install gpsd-3.21 on ubunt 18.04. This command install gpsd-3.17

Comment: @Donald `uboxtool` seems to be [not available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=uboxtool) in the repositories.

Comment: @N0rbert `uboxtool` is included as part of the `gpsd-clients` package

Comment: @DonaldSebastianLeung Maybe, but I do not see this file in [the filelist](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gpsd-clients/filelist). In any way I have upvoted your idea. I suppose that it is ubloxtool.

Comment: @N0rbert Your comment made me realize that I misspelt `ubxtool` as `uboxtool`, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: On Ubuntu Groovy, it's part of [gpsd](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=groovy&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=ubxtool). On Ubuntu Focal, it's part of [gpsd-clients](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=ubxtool). It's not part of any package [on 18.04 Bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=ubxtool).